# How to Convert ArrayList<Object> to a XML using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to convert ArrayList to xml using JAXB..

```
ArrayList<LDAPUser> myList = new ArrayList<LDAPUser>();

    myList = retrieveUserAttributes.getUserBasicAttributes(lastName,
            retrieveUserAttributes.getLdapContext());



    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(LDAPUser.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

     jaxbMarshaller.marshal(myList, sw);
     System.out.println(sw.toString());     
     return sw.toString();
```

...
but its not working, I am getting this error:

> 27-Aug-2012 10:43:58 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with
>   path [/Spring3-LDAP-WebService] threw exception [Request processing
>   failed; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: **class
>   java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this
>   context.] with root cause javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class
>   java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this
>   context.**    at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:554)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:470)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:314)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:243)
>     at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:96)
>     at
>   ie.revenue.spring.RestController.searchLdapUsersByLastNameTwo(RestController.java:69)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)...........

Please help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try to create a class that wraps your list and make it a xml root, e.g.:

```
@XmlRootElement
class LDAPUsers {
    private List<LDAPUser> users;
    ... get ... set ... constructor 
}
```

Then marshal LDAPUsers object.

Comment: I have the getters and setters,,,,constructor look like this.. public LDAPUsers()
    {
      if (ldapUser == null) {
             ldapUser = new ArrayList<LDAPUser>();
         }
    }..is it right ?

Comment: Yes, but in constructor the list will always be null unless you initialize it other way. `if` is not needed.