# Generics with jax-rs: JAXBException occurred : class java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf

I read now several articles about the subject of generics with jax rs, but I still can't make that simple example work:

Base response class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Base")
public class BaseMessage<T> {
    private String success = "success";
    private T data;

    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
 public Response search(final String searchTerm) {
        // Some DB stuff
        final Collection<SearchResult> filteredResults = dao.search(searchTerm);
        // Construct answer with some data payload
        final BaseMessage<Collection<SearchResult>> base = new BaseMessage();
        base.setData(filteredResults);
        final GenericEntity entity = new GenericEntity<BaseMessage<Collection<SearchResult>>>(base){};
        return Response.ok(entity).build();
    }
```

This always results in:
JAXBException occurred : class java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this context..

What I am missing here? CXF Version: 3.1.14

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to Convert ArrayList<Object> to a XML using JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139996/how-to-convert-arraylistobject-to-a-xml-using-jaxb?rq=1)?

Comment: @CannedMoose I did not find so far any working example with a base class I outlined above.